# What does $\Sigma^0_2$-hard and $\Pi^0_2$-hard for a TM's Acceptance Problem mean?

Tags: turing-machines, np-complete, np-hard

I'm reading about a Turing Machine $M$ and it says the problem of deciding whether M  accepts a string is "$\Sigma^0_2$-hard and $\Pi^0_2$-hard".

I haven't seen this kind of notation before and haven't found a good answer from searching. Is this a more specific form of saying NP-hard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's unrelated to **NP**-hardness.  $\Sigma_n^0$ and $\Pi_n^0$ are the levels of the [arithmetical hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy).  $\Sigma_2^0$ is the class of problems that can be decide by Turing machines that have an [oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine) for the halting problem and $\Pi_2^0$ is the class of problems whose complement is in $\Sigma_2^0$.

There is the corresponding notion of the [polynomial hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy), in which $\Sigma_1^\mathrm{P}$ is **NP** and $\Pi_1^\mathrm{P}$ is **co-NP**.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any information related to decidability that I can assume then for the Σ02 class of problems and  Π02 class of problems? It seems like given Σ02 is the class of problems that can be decided by a TM that has an oracle for the halting problem, that it cannot be semi-decidable (computably enumerable) and must be fully undecidable. And then given Π02 is its complement, Π02 problems must be fully undecidable as well. Is this the right thought process?

Comment: Also, if I wanted to prove that a problem is in the Σ02 class, should I show that there is a TM with an oracle for the halting problem that decides it? Thanks so much!

Comment: All decidable and recursively enumerable problems are in $\Sigma_0^2$, too: you can decide them with an oracle machine that just happens to never use the oracle, for example. This is just like every problem in **P** being in **NP**, too, except that we know that $\Sigma^0_2\neq \Sigma^0_1=\mathrm{RE}$ so a $\Sigma^0_2$-complete problem is definitely not RE. And, yes, to show that something is in $\Sigma^0_2$, you just need to show you can decide it with a Turing machine that has an oracle for the halting problem.